# Downloading large number of images in android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, download, android-image

I am developing an application which show large no of images in grid view. after that if user select any of this image it shows him in gallery view.
    So I have 2 questions as

1) Is their any way by which we can download large no of images as I get error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

2) Can I use same adapter I used to show grid view to gallery view.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1st question u have to scaled Bitmap otherwise it will not take large image (means large in size) like bellow,
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, 300,
                300, true));
so that a big size image scaled into specified size.

for 2nd question I think u have to take two separate adapter.(but not confirm)

Comment: Jyosna--- Thanks for quick reply
1) I am using  
Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 64, 64, true);
It doesn't worked.

Comment: How it not worked? Bcz i already tried in my app and its working.